# Calling MySql functions remotely fails

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I try to call user defined functions using remote connection it gives me error.

The thing is query without any functions runs fine for remote connection.

So how can I call functions remotely.

Query : `select jobcardid,sonno,sonnumber,getSalesOrderCountByStatus('completed',1)as finished,getSalesOrderCountByStatus('pending',sonnumber)as inprocess,getSalesOrderCountByStatus('',1)as total from tblm_jobcard where sonnumber like 'A121';`

Function :

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION getSalesOrderCountByStatus(v_status varchar(12), v_salesorderid integer) RETURNS int(11)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt integer(10);
if(length(v_status)>0) then 
select count(1) into cnt from tblm_jobcard where sonno = v_salesorderid and status = v_status;
else
select count(1) into cnt from tblm_jobcard where sonno = v_salesorderid ;
end if;
RETURN cnt;
```

On remote connection not getting anything just hangs up.

Comment: It's very difficult to help unless you tell us what error you are getting and give us more detail on what you were doing.

Comment: So either your function is buggy, or you're trying to call a stored procedure and not a function using select. Show some code, show the exact error you get.

Comment: Does the user you're connecting as have the `EXECUTE` privilege?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION getSalesOrderCountByStatus(v_status VARCHAR(12), v_salesorderid INTEGER) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt INTEGER(10);
IF(LENGTH(v_status)>0) THEN 
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO cnt FROM tblm_jobcard WHERE sonno = v_salesorderid AND STATUS = v_status;
ELSE
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO cnt FROM tblm_jobcard WHERE sonno = v_salesorderid ;
END IF;
RETURN cnt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```